# Return to a specific component/ div in a page when coming from a specific page in React JS (Without anchor tag)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working in an application where in a page it have a button. When I select the button it will go to another page.

I am using Push in UseHistory() to pass between pages. I know we can go to a specific div using anchor tag. But I don't want to use anchor tag. Can anyone help me how can I do that in react.

This is the button component I used to redirect to another page.

```
const { push } = useHistory();

return (
  <>
    {surveyDisableTime && <SurveyInfoBox />}
    <EmptyList
      image={<NoDataIcon />}
      title={formatMessage({ id: 'event.survey_response.assign_survey.heading' })}
      subtitle={formatMessage({ id: 'event.survey_response.assign_survey.subheading' })}
      onButtonClick={() => push(AppRoute.editEvent.replace(':eventId', event.id), { from: pathname })}
      buttonText={formatMessage({ id: 'event.survey_response.assign_survey.button_label' })}
      disabled={surveyDisableTime}
    />
  </>
);
```

This is the onclick function ->  `onButtonClick={() => push(AppRoute.editEvent.replace(':eventId', event.id), { from: pathname })}`

In the editEvent I need to go to a specific component. How can I do that?

Lets say this is the component of the page the router will reload to,

```
 return (
<div className={classes.container}>
  <div className={classes.creatEventContainer}>
    <div className={classes.formWrapper}>
      <BasicInfoSection
        institutionOptions={institutionOptions}
        seasons={seasons || []}
        isSeasonFieldDisabled={isSeasonFieldDisabled}
        {...props}
      />
      <EventLocation isVisible={!!isInPerson} errors={errors} register={register} {...props} />
      <SurveySelection
        isSurveyFieldDisabled={isSurveyFieldDisabled}
        isVisible={!!isSurvey}
        {...props}
      />
      <DateAndTimeSection control={control} errors={errors} />
      <NameRecordingsServicesSectionContainer
        fields={fields}
        remove={remove}
        append={append}
        languageVoices={languageVoices}
      />
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
)
```

I need to go to  component.

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: Do you want to render another component when the button is pressed?

Comment: Yes. Another component

Answer (score 0):

try useNavigate() instead because the hook useHistory is not supported in react-router-dom v6 anymore!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

if filledOutTheSurvey is false then return Survey component
but if the user fills out  then the state of filledOutSurvey would be true and AnotherComponent would render

```
...
const [filledOutTheSurvey, setFilledOutTheSurvey] = useState(false);

return (
  <div>
    {filledOutTheSurvey === true ? <AnotherComp/> : filledOutTheSurvey === false ? <Survey setFilledOutTheSurvey={setFilledOutTheSurvey} /> : null }
  </div>
)
...


function Survey({setFilledOutTheSurvey}){
  return <form onSubmit={() => setFilledOutTheSurvey(true)}>...</form>
}
```